# Pandas style for loop not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, highlight, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe in Pandas containing planet names and information about each planet. Planet names are stored under the column with the header 'planet'. I want to highlight rows of specific planets, Earth, Saturn, and Mars. For some reason, when I run this script and export as an Excel file, only the first planet in my highlight_planets list is highlighted. In this case, only Earth is highlighted (Saturn and Mars are not highlighted). If I move Saturn into the first position and Earth into the second position, only Saturn rows will be highlighted in the dataframe. How do I highlight all rows where my planet column contains Earth, Saturn, or Mars?

Thanks.

```
def highlight_sentiment(row):

    highlight_planets = ['Earth', 'Saturn', 'Mars']

    for m in highlight_planets:


        if row['planet'] == m:
           return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)
        else:
           return ['background-color: white'] * len(row)

df.style.apply(highlight_sentiment, axis=1)

df = df.style.apply(highlight_sentiment, axis=1)
df.to_excel("df_test.xlsx", index = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `for` loop, you `return` immediately if the planet is not the *first* value in your list.

Move the last `return` statement outside the `for` loop so it only returns a white background if the planet doesn't match *any* value in your list.

```
def highlight_sentiment(row):
    highlight_planets = ['Earth', 'Saturn', 'Mars']
    for m in highlight_planets:
        if row['planet'] == m:
           return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)
    return ['background-color: white'] * len(row)
```

As an aside, you could avoid the `for` loop altogether and just use `in`:

```
def highlight_sentiment(row):
    highlight_planets = ['Earth', 'Saturn', 'Mars']
    if row['planet'] in highlight_planets:
        return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)
    return ['background-color: white'] * len(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

The more standard approach to this problem is to build out a DataFrame of styles that can be built dynamically based on where planets are in the list using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
def highlight_sentiment(df_, highlight_planets):
    # Build DataFrame With Default Style
    styles_df = pd.DataFrame('background-color: white',
                             index=df_.index,
                             columns=df_.columns)
    # Update Styles based on condition
    styles_df.loc[
        df_['planet'].isin(highlight_planets), :
    ] = 'background-color: yellow'
    return styles_df


# Pass highlight_planets as an argument to allow more flexible styles
styler = df.style.apply(highlight_sentiment,
                        highlight_planets=['Earth', 'Saturn', 'Mars'],
                        axis=None)
# Use styler to write to excel
styler.to_excel("df_test.xlsx", index=False)
```

[image: styled table]

---

Sample Data and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'planet': ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth',
               'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn'],
    'data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
})
```

Comment: It's so weird seeing "Jupiter" instead of "Jupyter" hehe :). +1 from me!

Comment: I had it with a y first. Then I remembered that this is the planet XD